# Installing chrome browser on Android VM?

Tags: android, google-chrome, virtualbox

Is it possible to install chrome on a virtual machine of Android?

I installed Android 4.2
I tried downloading the chrome browser directly (file not supported)
I tried installing from the Chrome store (device not supported)

I need to get this working for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lately I've been using the Android emulator from Genymotion (http://www.genymotion.com/).  It's way better then the emulator you get with the Android SDK.

One of the huge benefits is that you can install google play, and therefore install any app from google play that you want.  Also, it works nicely with Google Maps V2.

Comment: awesome! I will try that out.